# Add a new column between other dataframe columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to add a new column with "NA"s in my dataframe:

```
     A       B
1    14379  32094
2   151884  174367
3   438422  449382
```

But I need it to be located between col. A and B, like this:

```
     A       C      B
1    14379   NA    32094
2   151884   NA    174367
3   438422   NA    449382
```

I know how to add col. C after col. B, but that is not helpful to me... Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In 2 steps, you can reorder the columns:

```
dat$C <- NA
dat <- dat[, c("A", "C", "B")]
         A  C          B
1  0.596068 NA -0.7783724
2 -1.464656 NA -0.8425972
```

You can also use `append`

```
dat <- data.frame(A = rnorm(2), B = rnorm(2))
as.data.frame(append(dat, list(C = NA), after = 1))

           A   C          B
1 -0.7046408  NA  0.2117638
2  0.8402680  NA -2.0109721
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use `data.table` you can use the function `setcolorder`. Note that `NA` is stored as logical variable, if you want to have the column initiated as an integer, double or character column, you can use `NA_integer`, `NA_real_` or `NA_character_`

eg

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)
# add column `C`  = NA 

DT[, C := NA]

setcolorder(DT, c('A','C','B'))
DT
##         A  C      B
## 1:  14379 NA  32094
## 2: 151884 NA 174367
## 3: 438422 NA 449382
```

You could do this in one line

```
setcolorder(DT[, C: = NA], c('A','B','C'))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the package tibble, which has a very interesting function (among many other) for that : add_column()

```
library(tibble)
df <- data.frame("a" = 1:5, "b" = 6:10)
add_column(df, c = rep(NA, nrow(df)), .after = 1)
```

That function is easy to use, and you can use the argument .before instead.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function to append columns onto (into) a data.frame. It allows you to name the column as well, and does a few checks...

```
append_col <- function(x, cols, after=length(x)) {
    x <- as.data.frame(x)
    if (is.character(after)) {
        ind <- which(colnames(x) == after)
        if (any(is.null(ind))) stop(after, "not found in colnames(x)\n")
    } else if (is.numeric(after)) {
        ind <- after
    }
    stopifnot(all(ind <= ncol(x)))
    cbind(x, cols)[, append(1:ncol(x), ncol(x) + 1:length(cols), after=ind)]
}
```

examples:

```
# create data
df <- data.frame("a"=1:5, "b"=6:10)

# append column 
append_col(df, list(c=1:5))

# append after an column index
append_col(df, list(c=1:5), after=1)

# or after a named column
append_col(df, list(c=1:5), after="a")

# multiple columns / single values work as expected
append_col(df, list(c=NA, d=4:8), after=1)
```

(One advantage of calling cbind at the end of the function and indexing is that characters within the data.frame are not coerced to factors as would be the case if using `as.data.frame(append(x, cols, after=ind))`)